# MTAudioProcessingTap on iOS - Should I use VLC or build a video player from scratch?

Tags: ios, video, core-audio, avplayer

I'm trying to build an iOS app that plays video files and does some interesting things using MTAudioProcessingTap. I need it to be able to play all sorts of formats, including some that are not supported by Apple. I'm thinking of branching out from VLC, but I can't figure out if it uses Core Audio/Video at any point or if it's running something else completely.

If it's not, is there a library I can use to take care of the 203572964 codecs being used out there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary note: I'm the developer of VLC for iOS so the following may be biased.

MobileVLCKit for iOS includes 2 different audio output modules. One of them is a high level module based on AudioQueue which is fairly incomplex but a bit slow. The other is based on AudioUnit, the low level framework of CoreAudio, quite a bit more complex, but way faster. Depending on your current experience, either module would be a good way to start.

Regarding the one library supporting all codecs thing: basically there are two forks of the same library: libav and FFmpeg. VLC supports either flavor and abstracts the complexity and the ever-changing APIs (which are a real pain if you intend to keep maintaining your app across multiple releases of those libraries). Additionally, we include a quite well performing OpenGL ES 2 video output module which is using shaders to do chroma conversation. All you need to do is embedding a UIView. MobileVLCKit handles the rest.

Speaking of MobileVLCKit: this is a thin ObjC layer on top of libvlc simplifying the use of this library in third party applications by abstracting most commonly used features.

As implicitly mentioned by HalR, libvlc does not use hardware accelerated decoding on iOS yet. We are working with the libav developers on a generic approach, but we are not quite there yet. Thus, we have to do all the decoding on the CPU, which leads to the heating but allows us to play virtually anything instead of H264/MP4 using the default, accelerated API.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure out how its playing the video, at its lower level, that perhaps is a sign that you should keep working with it instead of trying to outdo it.  Video processing is pretty difficult and often unsupported formats are unsupported due to patent issues.  I really haven't seen anything better than VLC that is publicly available.

VLC 2.1.x appears to use AudioToolbox and AVFoundation.

One other issue, though, is that when I was doing work with VLC, I was stunned how it turned my iPod Touch into a miniature iron, because it was working so hard to process the video.  Manually processing video is very processor intensive and really is a drain.  So your way or VLC could still have some additional issues.